# SQL Primary Key validation in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, validation, stored-procedures, sqltools

I have scoured the internet with no luck. I have attached links to the practice set I am working on, but I am creating a stored procedure that needs to update a row after checking if a foreign key from the one table matches with a corresponding primary key in another table. I'll attach my code so far (which isn't much), but I am honestly lost. I know how to create foreign key constraints like:

```
ALTER TABLE DRIVE
ADD CONSTRAINT TRUCK_NUM_FK FOREIGN KEY (TRUCK_NUM) REFERENCES TRUCK;
```

But I don't know how to do these things and more from a stored procedure.
Thank you!

Practice Description:
http://tinypic.com/r/2djxq4w/8
http://tinypic.com/r/sq61i1/8

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TRUCK_RETURN (TR_NUM IN NUMBER,TR_MILE IN NUMBER) AS
BEGIN
IF
UPDATE
```

Comment: Here is the link to my ERD: http://tinypic.com/r/ipv6fd/8

Comment: Use DRI ("ADD CONSTRAINT") and *not* a stored procedure to ensure basic relationships ..

Comment: It is not clear why do you need to check a foreign key in a procedure. Once you create a foreign key constraint, it is checked automatically on each operation on corresponding tables.

Comment: Yea, I don't think it makes much sense either. I would rather just add a constraint outside the procedure...but this practice problem seems to be asking me to do otherwise. Are their ways to put IF statements in my stored procedure to check these conditions?

Comment: How would you go about working this problem? Because it is requesting to display a custom message if the foreign key entered doesn't correspond with a primary key in another table, etc.  Not really sure about this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be exact but hopefully it will get you close:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TRUCK_RETURN (TR_NUM IN NUMBER,TR_MILE IN NUMBER) AS
BEGIN
IF TR_NUM IS NULL THEN
    Dbms_Output.PUT_LINE('Error: No truck number supplied.');
ELSE
    DECLARE TR NUMBER(10);
    SELECT TRUCK_NUM 
    INTO TR
    FROM TRUCK 
    WHERE TR_NUM = TRUCK_NUM;

    IF TR IS NOT NULL AND TR = TR_NUM THEN
       SELECT Truck_Mileage
           INTO TR
       FROM Truck
       WHERE Truck_Num = TR_NUM;

            IF TR_MILE >= TR THEN
                SELECT COUNT(*)
                INTO TR
                FROM DRIVE
                WHERE Truck_Num = TR_NUM
                      AND Drive_Status = ‘OUT’;

                IF TR = 1 THEN
                   UPDATE Drive
                   SET Drive_Status = ‘Received’
                   WHERE Truck_Num = TR_NUM
                   AND Drive_Status = ‘OUT’;
                ELSE 
                   Dbms_Output.PUT_LINE('Error: Truck has too many or not record of being out.’);
                END IF;
            ELSE
               Dbms_Output.PUT_LINE('Error: Truck mileage is less than previously recorded.’);
            END IF;
      ELSE 
         Dbms_Output.PUT_LINE('Error: Truck Number is incorrect.’);
      END IF;
END IF;
END TRUCK_RETURN;
```